# Gitlab- Getting 404 not found error when i call set estimate time using API

Tags: gitlab

I have called the API in below format but getting 404 not found error in response

> Format: https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/5/issues/93/time_estimate?duration=3h30m
>
> If i use below API then getting response with isues details
>
> > https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/5/issues/93/
> > but if i use first this for estimate time then it's not working

Please let me know if anyone knows the solution

Answer (score 0):

`gitlab.example.com` is just a placeholder url in docs, use `gitlab.com` instead